# Is it possible to use a variable for a javascript reference

Tags: javascript, html

Instead of:

```
<script src="/scripts/myJsFile.v1.js" type="text/javascript></script>
```

Have something like

```
<script src="/scripts/myJsFile." + versionVar + ".js" type="text/javascript></script>
```

This way when we update the js version files the user won't have to clear their cache.

Comment: What do you think the variable would come from?

Comment: If you are thinking about `versionVar` as JavaScript variable, then no, you cannot do it *that* way. You could, however, insert a script tag dynamically.

Comment: You cannot include a variable in plain HTML to define a JS source dynamically

Comment: We aren't using PHP. My guess would be to load the files from inside a script tag

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435785/dynamically-changing-stylesheet-path-not-working-in-ie-and-firefox

Comment: The script tag is part of the HTML - it's not executable JS code.

Comment: Is this static HTML, Classic ASP, ASP.Net, ASP-MVC, PHP...etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in that way, because you're mixing HTML and JavaScript together. HTML does not have JavaScript variables available.

What you can do, however, is adding the `<script>` tag dynamically, i.e. through JavaScript. That way, you obviously *are* able to use variables:

```
<script>
var versionVar = "1.0";

window.addEventListener('load', function() { // on load

    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script'); // create tag
    scriptTag.src = "/scripts/myJsFile." + versionVar + ".js" // set src attribute
    scriptTag.type = "text/javascript"; //set type attribute
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag); // append to <head>

}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in your HTML file directly. But still you can do this inside an script tag if `versopnVar` is a JavaScript variable in your `window` context:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', '/scripts/myJsFile.' + versionVar + '.js');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

At the end, it's not a good aproach doing this. Please read this article at a list apart to get informed.

**[Alternative Style: Working With Alternate Style Sheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/)**

Answer (score 2):

Check out how Google loads their Analytics.  Then maybe try something similar like:

```
(function() {
    var versionVar = 9;

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
ga.type = 'text/javascript';
ga.src =  'http://www' + '.google-analytics.com/ga' + versionVar + '.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to do something like

```
<script src="/scripts/myJsFile.js?v1" type="text/javascript></script>
```

Then, when you make and update:

```
<script src="/scripts/myJsFile.js?v2" type="text/javascript></script>
```

Which will cause most browsers to pull the file rather than pull from cache. This means that you won't have separate JS files. But will just be forcing the user to pull the most recent.

Also, if you want it to always pull the file you can, in a similar manner, append a random int.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that straight out.

One way is with some server side code.
For example in php:

```
<?php $version = "1.0"; ?>

<script src="/scripts/myJsFile.<?php echo $version ?>.js" type="text/javascript></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but we aren't using PHP

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly that way, but you can create a new script node with e.g. `document.createElement` and add it to the page.

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = ...
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

You can also use the `document.write` call to do the same...

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to update your page to update the variable.  Also, you'd have to update your javascript file name every time you changed it.

You can use a query string to make your JS unique.

```
<script src="/scripts/myJsFile.js?version=2" type="text/javascript></script>
```

marshall & I had the same Idea.

Also, you'd have to update your HTML file every time you updated your Javascript file.